# Unresponsive Flexbox: Reordering elements won't work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to push through a responsive Slack clone and for the next screen size, I hit a snag: it became 'unresponsive'.
The header as is stands is an image followed by text and for the first run where I wanted it that way, it was more than fine. However, for the next few iterations, I'd like to invert the order image and text.
I've already tried using order, row-reverse, and both at the same time to no avail.
Thanks in advance, your help is greatly appreciated.

```css
  body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

header div {
  margin: auto 4vw;
}

header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

header p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: distribute;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 961px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  header {
    flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /*  
    
    header :nth-child(1) {
      order: 2;
     }
     header :nth-child(2) {
      order: 1;
        } */
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="landing-img">
    <img src="./images/home_talking.png" alt="home_work_happening">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Where Work Happens</h1>
    <p>When your team needs to kick off a project, hire a new employee, deploy some code, review a sales contract, finalize next year's budget, measure an A/B test, plan your next office opening, and more, Slack has you covered.</p>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="user-add" name="e-mail" placeholder="E-Mail Address">
    </form>
    <button type="button" name="button">GET STARTED</button>
    <p id="headerSignin">Already using Slack? <a href="#">Sign in</a></p>
  </div>
</header>
```

The JSFiddle link can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/svmarinez/nos6rw8t/2/).

Comment: 1. Your `display: flex` rule is on the body, but your `flex-flow` rule is on the header. 2. You might not be hitting the breakpoint because of `orientation: portrait`.

Comment: What you exactly trying to do. explain us which content you want to reorder?

Comment: @KevinLee - I'm going to try taking out the `orientation:portrait` and see how that goes.
@Sharvan - In the header, I'd like for the `<div>` with text to be above the `<div class="landing img">` .

Comment: You will need to place the `display: flex` rule on the header then, not the body tag. Flexbox acts on direct children only.